# Vaadin - Request layout from a client side javascript component

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin

In a Vaadin project I am working on I have a client side javascript component (extending `AbstractJavascriptComponent`).

Occasionally the component size change, when that happen I want to trigger a re-layout in the parent container, Currently I am using a push message to trigger the layout request in the server side - which is a very inefficient way, I am looking for a way to trigger layout request directly from the javascript component-connector.

I looked at Vaadin documentation, the Vaadin book and many google results but with no luck.

Does anyone knows how to trigger a layout request from the javasript code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long googling session I found the solution, from javascript call:

```
vaadin.forceLayout();
```